# Como validar Data com Regex?

Tags: c#, string, regex

Estou tentando capturar uma data dentro de uma string usando regex, mas quando tento recupera a parte da string me retorna o seguinte erro:

> analisando "\TARIFA:([\d/]+)" - Sequência de escape não reconhecida
>   \T.

```
 match = Regex.Match(sbDados2.ToString(), @"\TARIFA:([\d\/]+)");

if (match.Success)
{
    objDocInterfDoc.inicioVigencia = Validacao.ConverterCampoDateTime(new Entrada
    {
        Conteudo = Funcoes.RemoverEspacos(match.Groups[1].Value)
    }).Data;
}
```

Minha string:

> {NÚMERO DO ORÇAMENTO~11727497~PROPOSTA DE SEGURO~EMISSAO:~ORIGEM N. PROPOSTA COMPANHIA~PORTO SEGURO CIA DE SEGUROS GERAIS~06/06/2016~69 - 63703827~AVENIDA RIO BRANCO, 1489 - CAMPOS ELÍSEOS~RENOVA APÓLICE PORTO SEGURO~TIPO DE SEGURO:68 - 759817~RENOVACAO PORTO~SÃO PAULO - CEP 01205-905~SITE: WWW.PORTOSEGURO.COM.BR~VIGÊNCIA DAS 24H DO DIA~TARIFA:08/06/2016~MAIO/2016~CÓDIGO DE REGISTRO JUNTO À SUSEP 05886~ATÉ AS 24H DO DIA~IMPRESSÃO:~08/06/2017~08/06/2016 - 09:26:12~C.N.P.J. 61.198.164/0001-60~SUSEP N.: 15414.000573/2006-42}

Quero recupera a parte TARIFA:08/06/2016.

Quando tento fazer através do [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dZ5cH0/1) , ele valida corretamente essa parte.

Comment: Tente usar esta [expressão regular](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZTVR0q3ffcB62PRd).

Comment: O que faltou na pergunta para  negativarem?

Comment: Não sei, para mim não há problema algum na pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apenas remova este carácter (a barra invertida - `\`), se eu bem entendi o que você precisa, sua regex não precisa dele pra funcionar.

O exemplo abaixo funciona certinho

```
var sbDados2 = "TARIFA:25/04/2016";     
var match = Regex.Match(sbDados2.ToString(), @"TARIFA:([\d\/]+)");
```

[Veja no dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JbCS88)

Comment: A razão para isso é que o `\t` é um ancora que significa `TAB`, e geralmente algumas ancoras tem o seu oposto : `\w` = `\W`, `\d` = `\D` que significa a  mesma captura só que negada. contudo o `\t` não o possui, por isso deve estar gerando o erro, o compilador deve estar procurando a ancora negada `\T`, que não existe.